# Происхождение слова "будоражить"

Tags: этимология

Основной вопрос в заголовке, а этот, как сопутствующий. - Как я понимаю, слово состоит из двух корней: "буд" и "раж", где буд - от будить, а раж - разить. Так ли это?

Comment: Нет, этимологические словари вашу версию не поддерживают: ["Будоражить"](http://endic.ru/krylov/Budorazhit-418.html)

Comment: А какова ваша версия ( на своей я не настаиваю, потому и задал вопрос публично)?

Comment: У меня личной версии нет, так как я не лингвист. В вопросах этимологии я полагаюсь на этимологические словари. Там по ссылке даны цитаты из нескольких. Самая первая: "Образовано от существительного будорага – "беспокойный человек". Будорага произведено от будор – "шум, гам, крик"; последнее еще встречается в диалектах в виде бутор".

Comment: Ваш комментарий выглядит как полноценный ответ. Почему бы вам в ответ его не оформить?

Answer (score 3):

Этимологический словарь Крылова:
["Будоражить"](http://endic.ru/krylov/Budorazhit-418.html)

> Образовано от существительного будорага – "беспокойный человек".
> Будорага произведено от будор – "шум, гам, крик"; последнее еще
> встречается в диалектах в виде бутор.

Этимологический словарь Фасмера:
["Будоражить"](http://endic.ru/fasmer/Budorazhit-2073.html)

> будоражить будора́жить бутара́жить "беспокоить, тревожить", будара́га
> "возбуждение; беспокойный человек"; Шахматов (ИОРЯС 7, 2, 354) считает
> форму на -т- первичной и предполагает связь с буторга́ "беспокойство",
> куторга́ – то же и торга́ть "дергать". Ср. также взбудура́жить,
> взбутура́жить "взбудоражить", смол. (Добровольский). Неясное слово. ••
> [будоражить, ср. Слов. Акад. 1847 г.: бударажить происходит,
> по-видимому, из укр. будара́жити "снаряжать челны, будары" (Кулиш.);
> см. Трубачев, в сб. "Этимологические исследования по русскому языку",
> 3, 1961, стр. 44. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.:
> Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Можно ещё дополнить Далем, хоть это и не этимологический словарь.

Толковый словарь Даля:
["Будоражить"](http://endic.ru/dal/Budorazhit-2195.html)

> буторажить кого, полошить, тревожить, беспокоить, волновать, мутить;
> приводить в беспорядок, держать в тревоге; -ся, тревожно и беспокойно
> суетиться. Полно народ будоражить, успокойся. Птица взбудоражилась,
> хорек в курятнике. Не мог добудоражиться его, добудиться и вызвать.
> Опять буран забудоражил. Все избудоражили, перерыли. Без толку
> набудоражили. Побудоражив, да угомонись. Пожар всех перебудоражил, всю
> ночь пробудоражились. Разбудоражился, не уймешь. **Будоражник м. -ница
> ж. будорага, будоражка об. будоражливый, беспокойный, тревожный,
> шумливый и суетливый человек, никому не дающий покоя.** Будорахнуть что,
> кур. шарахнуть, бросить, кинуть с грохотом; | ухнуть, набухать, налить
> вдруг не в меру. Будоражина ж. будорыжина, кол, тычок, торчок,
> тычинка.